# Android Java Widget showing no icon on list

Tags: android, widget, icons

This is my first attempt at writing an Android Java Widget. Currently once the APK is installed I see the main app icon ok but the widget list shows the widget with icon at all, just the text! I have been reading of similar problems and followed the proposed solutions but nothing has helped so far. The main app works ok and the widget can be placed on the home screen ok.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".TextViewWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="update.widgets.with.datavalue" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/text_view_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".DataValueReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></receiver>

    <activity android:name="com.streeterdjp.app.clientforspecviewv3webserver.TextViewWidgetProviderConfigureActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**text_view_widget_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="54dp"
android:minHeight="54dp"
android:minResizeWidth="54dp"
android:minResizeHeight="54dp"
android:initialLayout="@layout/text_view_widget_provider"
android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen"></appwidget-provider>
```

**text_view_widget_provider.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="54dp"
android:layout_height="54dp"
android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
android:background="#09C">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="#09C" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: I have the same problem. For me it works on the emulator, but on my Nexus 5 the icon will not show up in the widget selection list, it will only display the default android icon (green robot). Maybe something with the launcher?